# Unity and Chartboost loading problems

Tags: unity, ios, advertisements

I implemented chartboost in my ios game and locally it wors great.

I can receive ads.

Now my game is online but in the google analytics I get only error messages from
the game, meaning the chartboost ads fail to load.

Here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cft98lk27mt7p3s/cb.jpg?dl=0

The iage show google analytics registering only failed loads and
there is no single successfull ad load?

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a program like Charles Web Proxy to see what network calls your game makes to Chartboost. Your game should be sending calls at every bootup and when it caches or shows an interstitial or MoreApps page. If you're not seeing these calls at bootup and when you expect to show a Chartboost ad, look through the integration documentation to be sure you did everything right.

If those steps don't work, you may need to call Chartboosts support line and have them walk you through additional steps.